# recursion on an ArrayList

Tags: arrays, list, recursion, arraylist

I'm doing a university assessment and im struggling with the concept of recursion on an array list. I'm trying to create a family tree type output where i can access mother, then loop back in and add the mother of the mother and do the same for father but i dont know how to recursively send my information back to my ArrayList. Heres my code thus far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Person {

    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Person mother;
    private Person father;

    public Person(String first, String last) {
        firstname = first;
        lastname = last;
    }

    public void print(String indent) {

        System.out.println(indent + "------------------------");
        System.out.println(indent + firstname + " " + lastname);
        System.out.println(indent + "------------------------");

        if (mother != null) {
            System.out.println(indent + firstname + "'s mother:");
            mother.print(indent + "   ");
        }
        if (father != null) {
            System.out.println(indent + firstname + "'s father:");
            father.print(indent + "    ");
        }

    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
        // to be completed
        // if we have no last name use the name of the father
    }

    // return an arraylist of all ancestors of this person
    public ArrayList<Person> ancestors() {
        ArrayList<Person> result = new ArrayList<Person>();

        if (mother != null) {           
            result.add(mother);
            // I dont know what to put here but i want it to go back to array list
           // i dont understand the syntax.
        }
        if (father != null) {           
            result.add(father);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The recursive case occurs when mother or father are non-null. We add them to the ancestors array and then make a recursive call to retrieve an ArrayList containing their own ancestors. We append that result to the end of the ancestors array, accumulating the result of the recursion in the returned ArrayList.

The base case occurs when mother and father are both null. In this case an empty ArrayList is returned (and since no additional recursive calls are made, the recursion ends).

Here is an example of how you could write this:

```
public ArrayList<Person> ancestors() 
{
    ArrayList<Person> ancestors = new ArrayList<Person>();

    if (mother != null)
    {
        ancestors.add(mother);
        ArrayList<Person> mothersAncestors = mother.ancestors();   // recursive call
        ancestors.addAll(mothersAncestors);                        // append result to end
    }

    if (father != null)
    {
        ancestors.add(father);
        ArrayList<Person> fathersAncestors = father.ancestors();   // recursive call
        ancestors.addAll(fathersAncestors);                        // append result to end
    }

    return ancestors;
}
```